# __VA_ARGS__ Macro expansion

Tags: objective-c, macros, variadic-functions

I'm trying to get my macro to work like `NSLog()` which accepts variable arguments. Code below causes parse issues.

What is the correct way to define this?

```
#define TF_CHECKPOINT(f, ...) \
do { \
NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:f arguments:__VA_ARGS__] autorelease]; \
[TestFlight passCheckpoint:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %@", [self class], s]]; \
} while (0)
```

Comment: I'm not sure how you mean _variable arguments_ because the `__VA_ARGS__` already represents variable arguments for the macros, so you can use the following macro as you would use the `NSLog(...)` normally: `#define AnotherLog(...) NSLog(__VA_ARGS__)` and after it, it would be a valid line in you source code: `AnotherLog(@"%d, %@", 1, @"text"); what exactly is your final goal?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You forgot the opening bracket for the `autorelease` message.

Moreover `-[NSString initWithFormat:arguments:]` expects a `va_list` argument, whereas `__VA_ARGS__` is replaced by all the passed arguments. Here, you need to use `-[NSString initWithFormat:]` or `+[NSString stringWithFormat:]`.

Finally, you may prefix `__VA_ARGS__` with `##`. By doing so, the preceding comma is deleted when there is no argument.

Try this:

```
#define TF_CHECKPOINT(f, ...) \
do { \
NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:(f), ##__VA_ARGS__]; \
[TestFlight passCheckpoint:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %@", [self class], s]]; \
} while (0)
```

Comment: Ok, stupid mistake on my part for forgetting the opening bracket.